# Installshield LE Shortcut Display Version Info

Tags: wpf, shortcut, installshield-le, assemblyinfo

I'm using installshield LE to deploy my WPF application.

I have both start menu and desktop shortcuts and would like to display some version info about the wpf application.

Ideally I'd like to display the Assembly information.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.